# Does every non $q$ colorable graph contain a $K_{q+1}$ for $q \geq 3$?

Tags: coloring

Given a graph over $n$ vertices and an integer $3 \leq q < n$, I am wondering if every **non** $q$-colorable graph must contain a $K_{q+1}$. I came across this question when thinking about an efficient way to decide whether a graph contains a $K_{q+1}$. If this would be the case the statement would also not be very likely because of the NP-completeness of the coloring problem.
The brute force way of deciding whether a graph containts a $K_{q+1}$ must check all $\binom{n}{q+1}$ subsets of vertices. Also the [subgraph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) is NP-complete, but this is a much more general problem then the one of finding a $K_{q+1}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is clearly false. Take, for example, the 5-cycle graph, which cannot be 2-colored but yet does not contain a $K_3.$

Comment: Thank You very much! Do You know if the statement holds for $q \geq 3$? I never considered the case of $q=2$. I will edit the question by restricting it to $q \geq 3$.

Comment: Testing for existence of a $K_q$ is clearly polynomial in the number $n$ of vertices:Just loop over $q$-Tuples and check the edges between its members